# (node:8472) [DEP_WEBPACK_DEV_SERVER_ON_AFTER_SETUP_MIDDLEWARE]

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm-start, npx

so i got error when i started my react-app

```
(node:8472) [DEP_WEBPACK_DEV_SERVER_ON_AFTER_SETUP_MIDDLEWARE] DeprecationWarning: 'onAfterSetupMiddleware' option is deprecated. Please use the 'setupMiddlewares' option.
(Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:8472) [DEP_WEBPACK_DEV_SERVER_ON_BEFORE_SETUP_MIDDLEWARE] DeprecationWarning: 'onBeforeSetupMiddleware' option is deprecated. Please use the 'setupMiddlewares' option.
```

does anyone have a solution i'm still confused after i search in google and anywhere i got the error code which is difference not 8472 or there is a different meaning.

after i try it 'node --trace-deprecation ...'  shows this

```
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:936
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\User\Desktop\tesla-clone\...'
←[90m    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933:15)←[39m
←[90m    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27)←[39m
←[90m    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)←[39m
←[90m    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47←[39m {
  code: ←[32m'MODULE_NOT_FOUND'←[39m,
  requireStack: []
}
```

after i try node --trace-deprecation node_modules/.bin/react-scripts start then show this

```
basedir=$(dirname "$(echo "$0" | sed -e 's,\\,/,g')")
          ^^^^^^^

SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
←[90m    at Object.compileFunction (node:vm:352:18)←[39m
←[90m    at wrapSafe (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1031:15)←[39m
←[90m    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1065:27)←[39m
←[90m    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)←[39m
←[90m    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)←[39m
←[90m    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)←[39m
←[90m    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)←[39m
←[90m    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47←[39m
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242200/discussion-on-question-by-roihan-adhen-node8472-dep-webpack-dev-server-on-af).